# chameleon add line to fill-slot

Tags: python, macros, pyramid, chameleon

i have a website with a dynamic number of widgets, the pyramid view(views.py) call the page, and send the data:

View.py:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/home.pt')
def home_view(request):
    widgets = #do sql stuff#
    return widgets
```

layout.t:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div  class="container">
    <div tal:omit-tag="" metal:define-slot="content"/>
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <more tal:omit-tag metal:define-slot="js-more"></more>
 </body>
</html>
```

home.pt:

```
<div metal:fill-slot="js-more">
 <script src="pagespecific.js"></script>
</div>
<div metal:use-macro="load: layout.pt">
  <div metal:fill-slot="content">
   Page Content!!!!
  </div>
  <div class="widgets-stuff">
    <div class="modulecontent" tal:repeat="_widgets widgets">
     <div tal:omit-tag="" metal:use-macro="load: widgets/${_widgets.template}.pt" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

widgetSample.pt:

```
<div class="morewidgetstuff">
 A widget!
</div>
```

i wanted to able to add a new js on the widget template, something like this:

widgetSample.pt:

```
<div metal:add-to-slot="js-more">
 <script src="widgetspecific.js"></script>
</div>
<div class="morewidgetstuff">
 A widget!
</div>
```

ps: i know this doesn't make much sense, this is just an example

Comment: Ah, missed the `ProxyExpr` wrapper in the code, you are correct, it takes a TALES expression.. So what is your question then exactly?

Comment: Ah, you cannot fill slots in the 'parent' template from a included macro, no. You'll have to fill that slot with an explicit, separate loop over `widgets` checking for JS to include.

Comment: that's what i thought, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fill the slot (thus adding any required JavaScript for your widgets) in the template that renders all widgets (in your case `home.pt`).

That's only reasonable, because if you've got two widgets that need the same resource, you'll want to include it only once. It's much easier to determine the unique set at the level where you've got the set of all widgets.